# how to fix "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" : Codeigniter

Tags: php, html

this is the coding of the controller

```
public function daftar_membimbing()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('status') != "login") {
        redirect(base_url('login'));
    } else {
        if ($this->session->userdata('tipe') == "admin") {
            redirect(base_url('home_admin'));
        }
    }

    $nidn = $this->session->userdata('nidn');
    $kode = $this->Judul_model->membimbing($nidn)->result();

    $data['judul'] = $this->Judul_model->getmembimbing($kode)->result();

    $this->load->view('pages/static/header_dosen');
    $this->load->view('pages/dosen/daftar_membimbing', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/static/footer');
}
```

this is the coding of the model

```
public function membimbing($nidn)
{
    $this->db->select('kode');
    $this->db->from('dosen');
    $this->db->where('nidn =', $nidn);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}

public function getmembimbing($kode)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('judul');
    $this->db->where($kode);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

anh how to fix the error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: What is the line number where you getting the error?

Comment: in here

   $this->db->where($kode);